# Admin redirects to /login although REMOTE_USER is provided

Tags: django, django-authentication

I configured Authentication using REMOTE_USER in a Django project, replacing the default ModelBackend. However, when I call an admin page it still redirects to the login page. I tested with:

```
curl -i -H 'REMOTE_USER: ruser1' http://localhost:8765/admin/myapp/mytable/
Location: http://localhost:8765/admin/login/?next=/admin/myapp/mytable/
```

[edit: this is wrong - I tested as well with
REMOTE_USER=ruser1 ./manage.py runserver]

The remote user has been added to the auth_user table.

My related config snippets are:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `REMOTE_USER` as an HTTP header, otherwise users would be able to spoof the header and log in as any user they wanted.

In production, the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable is set by the server, e.g. Apache or Nginx. If you are testing using the development server, you can set the remote user with

```
REMOTE_USER=ruser1 ./manage.py runserver
```

Any requests to the dev server will be processed with `ruser1` as the logged in user.

Comment: You are of course right, the curl example that I gave is wrong. But I tested with the ENV var before that, and verified in the debugger that the authentication backend does receive the remote_user. So the user has been added to auth_user - the problem remains.